# Sencha Architect - TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'reader.getReaderType')

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Sencha Touch Architect is giving me this error when I set-up a store, a rest proxy and then try and load data into the store.

**TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'reader.getReaderType')**

Has anyone had this issue or knows a work-around?